# How to redirect from an old php script to a new php script using mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

It's my first request here and hopefully I won't upset anyone.

Here's my story:

I have looked all over this place for a solution and wasn't able to find one. Here's hoping that someone can give some input.

I've basically managed to use Apache's **mod_rewrite** to create SEO-Friendly urls for my website.

E.g. Old path *www.hostname/index1.php?session=user* is now rewritten as *www.hostname/user*, which results into a SEO Friendly URL address.

However, the old path is still valid. I need to somehow redirect all the incoming old *index1.php* requests to the newer URLs, the SEO-Friendly ones, for the search engines to transfer the link popularities to the new ones. I believe I may have an infinite-loop redirect and that's why it's not working.

My code so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

## Redirect still valid old links to SEO friendly ones
RewriteRule ^/?index1\.php\?session=user$ /user [R=301]

## Catch the above and rewrite the URL 
RewriteRule ^/?user/?$ /index1.php?session=user [QSA,L]
```

The above rules never get *hit* when the *htaccess* file is parsed.

It hit me that I might be doing some sort of redirect loop here so I thought about renaming the **index1.php** file to **index2.php** and create something like:

```
## Redirect still valid old links to SEO friendly ones
RewriteRule ^/?index1\.php\?session=user$ /user [R=301]

## Catch the above and rewrite the URL 
RewriteRule ^/?user/?$ /index2.php?session=user [QSA,L]
```

However, that failed too.

What would be the best approach to this? What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the `?`) in a rewrite rule, so you can't match against the `session=` part. You also can't simply match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` var because that gets populated by you other rule when it rewrites the SEO friendly URL to the one with the query string. So you need to match against the actual request:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index1\.php\?session=([^&]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%2?%3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, indeed this worked out just fine. The only problem I have now is that the QUERY_STRING gets ported to the new URL. It's something like _www.hostname/user?session=user_ at the moment. Hopefully  I will get it right after a documentation revisit. :)

Comment: what if I had multiple parameters in the query string?

E.g. Redirect **www.hostname/index1.php?session=user&page=account&other_field=[dynamic_value]** to **www.hostname/user/page/dynamic_value/** ?

How could I apply this and send the dynamic values over, for the 'catch' RewriteRules?

Comment: @JonLin, please could you explain the bit on why query string rule would fail to match here? I'm not able to comprehend why your rule works and mine not. For an index.php request I believe both should have received session query parameter.

Comment: @BAS The query string (the `?session=user&page=account&other_field=[dynamic_value]`) *is not part of the string* used to match against the regex pattern in a `RewriteRule`. The query string is stripped off and only the URI is passed into a rewrite rule.

Comment: @JonLin, I would appreciate if you could help me out with my query above. I'm sure you would understand how sometimes these little things can really bug us. :)

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Not sure what question you are referring to

Comment: @JonLin great explanation! 

Now I understand. I even figured a workaround of my own, based on your first suggestion of the above solution in which I use the **%{QUERY_STRING}** parameter, even though it's not as compact (or optimized) as your latest update (which also includes dynamic query parameters). I'll add everything as soon as possible in the original question post, along with the credits you guys deserve.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `.htaccess` rules to

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

## Redirect still valid old links to SEO friendly ones
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !no-redir [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} session=user [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?index1\.php$ /user? [R=301,NC,L]

## Catch the above and rewrite the URL 
RewriteRule ^/?user/?$ /index1.php?session=user&no-redir [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. I've tested it extensively. Thank you for the suggestion, and I appreciate your logic behind it.

Comment: Was user a dynamic value or actual text "user"?

Comment: You can't match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` because that gets populated by OP's internal forward rule where it rewrites the SEO friendly URL to the one with the query string, in this rule: `RewriteRule ^/?user/?$ /index2.php?session=user [QSA,L]` What doesn't get rewritten is `%{THE_REQUEST}` and hence can be used for external redirect as in @Jon's answer.

Comment: @anubhava You mean OP's first rule right that has the comment "## redirect still valid ..."? But that's being replaced by my rules. So, my first rule should receive the session value as query string. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your code might work if you append `?` at the end of first rule like: `RewriteRule ^/?index1\.php$ /user? [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: @anubhava Oh man, you figured it out. Of course, the first rule must have caused a 500 and gone into the loop and `?` would make sure it goes to the second rule after the redirect. Thank you, thank you! But, the use of `%{QUERY_STRING}` is correct right? Assuming my rules would have replaced OP's completely.

Comment: Yes `%{QUERY_STRING}` would have worked but you had to use an additional query parameter `no-redir`, which you could avoid by using `%{THE_REQUEST}`.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, that's fine. I was bugged thinking I have a fundamental flaw with my logic and I can't use `%{QUERY_STRING}` at all from what I interpreted by Jon Lin's answer. But, know I see how the use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` lets me avoid using `no-redir` (which is harmless as well since it's used for internal routing only). Thank you for your time! :)

Comment: I can't help but notice that my little question turned up some interesting dialog around here. I am proud to say that I have learned so much from everything that's been discussed here. I will have to try your suggestion again @RaviThapliyal with the new modifications. I told you, I appreciated your logic and seen it working, however my poor experience with http htaccess directives and RegExs couldn't figure out why it didn't work. Thank you all for the great input. You have my deepest respect!